# cmake linking with cpprestsdk on windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have started new cmake project for c++ in vs2017. And followed the cpprestsdk instructions to build on windows.

```
PM> vcpkg install cpprestsdk cpprestsdk:x64-windows

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
find_package(cpprestsdk REQUIRED)
```

the error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     CMake Error at CMakeProject1/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
>   By not providing "Findcpprestsdk.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
>   project   has asked CMake to find a package configuration file
>   provided by   "cpprestsdk", but CMake did not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "cpprestsdk"
>   with   any of the following names:
>
> ```
> cpprestsdkConfig.cmake
> cpprestsdk-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "cpprestsdk" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
>   set   "cpprestsdk_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
>   files.  If   "cpprestsdk" provides a separate development package or
>   SDK, be sure it has   been installed.
>
> C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL
>   STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe
>   -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\Users\berkin1\CMakeBuilds\c5a5aa79-502a-4e33-9202-078595e40dda\install\x64-Debug
>   (default)"  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe"
>   -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe"
>   -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL
>   STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe"
>   "c:\users\berkin1\source\repos\CMakeProject1" returned with exit code:
>   1 CMake Error at CMakeProject1/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):   By
>   not providing "Findcpprestsdk.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
>   has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
>   "cpprestsdk", but CMake did not find one.   Could not find a package
>   configuration file provided by "cpprestsdk" with   any of the
>   following names:
>       cpprestsdkConfig.cmake
>       cpprestsdk-config.cmake   Add the installation prefix of "cpprestsdk" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set   "cpprestsdk_DIR" to a
>   directory containing one of the above files.  If   "cpprestsdk"
>   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has   been
>   installed.        c:\users\berkin1\source\repos\CMakeProject1\CMakeProject1/CMakeLists.txt    5

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked to add the following commandline options to cmake:

`-DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<vcpkg path>\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake`